# Rails .Rmd files rendering using Kumquat gem - .Rdata not loading

Tags: r, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having a rails app where i use https://github.com/kickstarter/kumquat gem to render .Rmd files. It works perfectly.

I want to load **.RData** like below

```
load("R/created.RData")
```

which is not working now. I am confused that whether Kumquat gem can process **.RData** or not. Stuck for two days. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried reading in other types of files? If it works for RDS-files, then just use those instead of RData.

Comment: @EsbenEickhardt No i haven't tried RDS files. Thanks for your help. Will try that.

Comment: @EsbenEickhardt Had tried .rds but it is for single object right? We need to process multiple objects and hence .RData is what we need.

Comment: True, it is for single objects, but you can just place your objects in a list.